# Flutter container stuck to size

Tags: wordpress, flutter

I am developing an app that is a grid of wordpress articles.
My problem is this: I want each container to be longer than wider but cannot change from a square.

I also get the following error:

```
flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY
╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: The following message was thrown during layout:
flutter: A RenderFlex overflowed by 5.9 pixels on the bottom.
flutter:
flutter: The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.vertical.
flutter: The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and
flutter: black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.
flutter: Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the
flutter: RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
flutter: This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be
flutter: seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a
flutter: ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex,
flutter: like a ListView.
flutter: The specific RenderFlex in question is:
flutter:   RenderFlex#b5cf8 OVERFLOWING
flutter:   creator: Column ← DecoratedBox ← Padding ← Container ← RepaintBoundary-[<0>] ←
flutter:   NotificationListener<KeepAliveNotification> ← KeepAlive ← AutomaticKeepAlive ← SliverGrid ←
flutter:   MediaQuery ← SliverPadding ← Viewport ← ⋯
flutter:   parentData: <none> (can use size)
flutter:   constraints: BoxConstraints(w=177.5, h=177.5)
flutter:   size: Size(177.5, 177.5)
flutter:   direction: vertical
flutter:   mainAxisAlignment: start
flutter:   mainAxisSize: max
flutter:   crossAxisAlignment: center
flutter:   verticalDirection: down
flutter:   ◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤
flutter: ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 5.9 pixels on the bottom.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 5.9 pixels on the bottom.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 5.9 pixels on the bottom.
flutter: Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by 5.9 pixels on the bottom.
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: share your code

Answer (score 0):

When any views/widgets overlapping at that time this issue occur. to reduce this issue you have put your widget inside stack or scroll-view.

like this,

```
new Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 18.0, right: 18.0),
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    view1,
                    view2,
                    view3,
                    view4,
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          )
```

Try this or share your code here to get more idea about your issue.